# dynamically add Html Check Mark Character in textbox

Tags: jquery, html, unicode

I am trying to add ✔ character (i.e Heavy Check Mark) in the text box.
If I hardcode it as a value to the textbox it does show proper check mark in the browser.
However If I try to update the value dynamically to "✔" it does not reflect in the browser.
I tried

```
1.  $('#txtBox').val(result.value);

2.  $('#txtBox').val('&#10004;');

3.  $('#txtBox').attr('value',result.value);

4.   $('#txtBox').attr('value','&#10004;');
```

All these combinations.
Even then It do not show check mark if I try to show the check mark dynamically.
Please help

Comment: Can you please give me an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to directly add ✔ character.

```js
$('#addChkBox').click(function () {
    $('#txtBox').val('✔');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtBox"/>
<button id="addChkBox">Add CheckBox</button>
```

Comment: Chitrang,I tried the same thing lastly. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do is :

```
var abc = $('#txtBox').html('&#10004;').text();


$('#txtBox').val(abc);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pramodga/nL9L8j8k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('#txtBox').append('&#10004;');
```

I'm not sure how you're defining `result.value`, so I can't speak to how you'd use this.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oe16xdbr/2/

Comment: I believe he wants it to use on a `textbox` or as we might also know it, an input with type `text`. In that case your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your added the right charset

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click_me').click(function(){
        $('#Box').val($('#Box').val() + '✔');
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/synL1wLa/